# A finite graph G has an even number of vertices with odd valency.

Tags: graph-theory

Theorem: A finite graph G has an even number of vertices with odd valency.

Now, I draw a finite graph :

[image]

The number of vertices is 4. And Degree(1) = 1, Degree(2) = 2, Degree(3) = 2, Degree(4) = 1.

But the theorem say : **Each vectices with odd valency**. And I see degree of 2 and 3 are 2.

I don't understand it. Can you expland it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct interpretation should be "If $G$ is a finite graph, then the number of vertices with odd valency is even."

You're interpreting it as "If $G$ is a finite graph with an even number of vertices, then each vertex has odd valency."

Answer (score 1):

No, everything is right! What are vertices with odd valence? 1 and 4. There are exactly two vertices — even number